# Update attribute in Core Data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, insert-update

I know that this has been answered many times but I can't seem to get mine to work.

I have an entity called `SchoolName`s and this has a single attribute called `nameOfSchool`. I want to be able to update this attribute.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SchoolName"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"NameOfSchool" ascending:YES]];
NSError *errorLoading = nil;
self.schoolNames = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errorLoading];

NSLog(@"%d", self.schoolNames.count );
```

I can see in the `NSLog` that I am loading my data into the `schoolNames` array. But I have no idea how to update an entry in the array and then save that back to the entity.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin's suggestion is really valid. I upvoted ;).

The other way is to access the attribute you are interested in through KVC (if you have not subclassed the entity `SchoolName`).

```
for (NSManagedObject *schoolObject in [self schoolNames]) {
    [schoolObject setValue:@"yourNewValue" forKey:@"nameOfSchool"];
}
```

Also remember to save, on the contrary changes will be only on memory (not in the store).

P.S. In the code I suppose that `nameOfSchool` is of type `NSString`. Other values are possible.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `executeFetchRequest` is an array of *SchoolName* objects. To update these objects, you just assign a new value to the attribute:

```
for (SchoolName *sn in self.schoolNames) {
    sn.nameOfSchool = ... ; // new value;
}
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Save failed, handle error ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this also and it works - thanks